# Conditionally combine enumeratees

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

did anybody come across the piece of code to implement conditional combination of enumeratees? Essentially given I have

```
val decideEnumeratee : Enumerate[A,Either[L,R] = Enumerate.map(a=>???)
val leftSideEnumeratee : Enumeratee[L,B] = Enumeratee.map(l=>???)
val rightEnumeratee: Enumeratee[R,B] = Enumeratee.map(r=>???)
```

I want to have implementation of the following combinator:

```
def either[L,R,B](left:Enumeratee[L,B], right,Enumeratee[R,B]): Enumeratee[Either[L,R],B] = ???
```

Has anybody come across the similar enumeratee implementation?

Comment: Do you mean something like the wye or either function in scalaz-stream (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/stream/Process.scala)?

Comment: yes exactly. however it seems that with Enumeratee it is no go, respectivelly you cannot do that in case you hold any processing state within combined Enumeratees.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a definition for `either`:

```
def either[A, B, C](left: Enumeratee[A, C], right: Enumeratee[B, C])
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new Enumeratee[Either[A, B], C] {
    def applyOn[IR](inner: Iteratee[C, IR]) = {
      val (liter, lenum) = Concurrent.joined[C]
      val (riter, renum) = Concurrent.joined[C]
      val liter2 = Enumeratee.mapConcat { x: Either[A, B] =>
          x.left.toSeq
        } compose left transform liter
      val riter2 = Enumeratee.mapConcat { x: Either[A, B] =>
          x.right.toSeq
        } compose right transform riter
      val fresult = lenum interleave renum apply inner
      Enumeratee.zip(liter2, riter2) mapM { _ => fresult }
    }
}
```